# How to change the default route point static html files in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how can we point the default file to something like **index.html** instead of the default action **Home/Index**

Comment: I would like to use the static page as my landing page instead of a dynamic one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS configure the default document to be index.html at the top of the list?

Or you could add an IgnoreRoute to your global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");
   ...
```

Comment: i think this is the opposite of what he is asking.  he wants to use the index.html as his homepage not ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

I found that under IIS 6 at least the default document pickup was interfered with when you used a wildcard catchall to route most requests into the MVC.

My solution (just for the root path in my case) was as follows:
(in global.asax)

if (Request.Path == "" || Request.Path == "/")
            {
                Response.Redirect(Request.Path + "index.htm",true);
                return;
            }

This picked up the request and redirected it to the correct location. Rewriting the path using Context.RewritePath(Request.Path + "index.htm"); instead of the redirect also seems to work.
A further revision would probably be to see if the final character of the path is '/' and if so check whether the corresponding file (thatpath/index.htm) exists and redirecting if it does... this would effectively allow MVS to keep working while providing logic so any folders that do exist that have a default document like that will serve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default controller action by adding or changing a **route** in the `Global.asax.cs` file of your project.

In the template, the following is included:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = null });
```

If you want to point to a different controller action by default, just change the values in the anonymous type on the fourth line of code above.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("");
```

to my route configuration.  This ignores the root folder and if you have an index.html file in your root, it will get picked up.